# Using printWriter to write to a byte buffer?

Tags: java, buffer, printwriter

I wasn't sure if this was possible. 
I tried doing something like

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(byteStream);
pw.write("TEST STRING");
```

When I try to do `System.out.println(byteStream.toString())`; It prints an empty string.
     When I try to do `System.out.println(byteStream.size())`, it prints 0, 
    meaning the byte buffer in ByteArrayOutputStream is empty after print writer writes to it? I'm not sure if this is the only way to use PrintWriter to rite to byte array. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Your output needs to be flushed to the stream.  You can do one of the following:

1. Make the `PrintWriter` auto-flushable using [the appropriate constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter-java.io.OutputStream-boolean-) and call `println` to include a line-feed character.

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(byteStream, true);
pw.println("TEST STRING");
```

2. Or, you can flush it explicitly.

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(byteStream);
pw.write("TEST STRING");
pw.flush();
```

3. Closing the `PrintWriter` flushes the output (as already indicated in a comment).

Comment: They could also `pw.close()` if they are done writing.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek That's right; I've added that to my answer.

Comment: Oh interesting the second option worked! I'm wondering why the first option didn't =/